# What technologies are you using to create your desktop UI

Tags: user-interface

For the last few years i have been working as a web developer.  So my desktop development skills are a little rusty.  I am aware of Adobe AIR, winforms, WFP and silverlight 3.0. I was wandering what other UI frameworks/technologies people are using to implement desktop applications.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to do. Some of the bigger toolkits for creating GUIs (among others) are QT (http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/), GTK (http://www.gtk.org/) and wxwidgets (http://wxwidgets.org/). Each of them allows you to code in a couple of different languages and use the GUIs on different platforms. There are plenty other toolkits though, which might fit your needs better (eg. more leight-weight ones).

Answer (score 2):

AIR is pretty cool, I've enjoyed writing projects for it as there are a lot less limitations compared to winforms.  winforms is quick and easy to use though in Visual Studio.

I think the list you've got is pretty good to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome.  Our "desktop" UI is browser-based.

Answer (score 1):

there's lots of different GUI stuff, SWING for java and .net forms are common.

Answer (score 1):

besides what you listed, you'll also hear about Win32 and MFC (both c++), Tk (which is common with scripting languages like perl/python), the hardware languages OpenGl, glu, and glut (cross platform), DirectX (windows), and X Window System (X11) on linux (and Mac) and Cocoa and Carbon on Mac.

There are many others, but these are ones that I've seen used regularly.

Answer (score 1):

WinForms is the default platform used to develop desktop applications using .NET framework (and Visual Studio 2002, 2003, 2005 and 2008). It's really a wrapper around the Win32 API that deals with `CreateWindow` and managing the messages sent to that window.

WinForms uses GDI/GDI+ technology while WPF (an exciting new platform offering a LOT of potential) utilizes GDI/GDI+ and DirectX (some parts at least, such as bitmap effects, transitions, fading).

Silverlight is a toned down Web version of WPF. Silverlight 3.0 allows developers to create a rich internet experience without the need to run the application inside a browser. Definitely something to keep an eye out for!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the langage and the platform you're programming for. For C++, you can use either : Qt and its RAD tool: Qt designer,  GTK+ / gtkmm or wxWidgets among others..

Answer (score 0):

In terms of GUI design, I depend heavily on QT right now (py and c++ QT).
I recommend an excellent book: [Rapid GUI Design with QT](http://www.amazon.ca/Rapid-GUI-Programming-Python-Definitive/dp/0132354187)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) sounds pretty cool.